# Manipulate SQL Server spatial data

Tags: sql-server, spatial

I have a table containing a map. The data looks like this

```
select 
    location.ToString() 
from 
    mp_ices_areas 
where 
    ICES_AREA in ('IIIa', 'IVa', 'IVb')
```

results in this:

```
POLYGON ((11.45850012 58.98790008, 11.4651 58.98660003, ...
POLYGON ((7.00000056 58.05548352, 7.00010064 58.05550053, ...
etc.
```

The map have been updated, so the "step looking" border is now a straight line. This is visualized using this query:

```
DECLARE @g1 geography = 'LINESTRING (7.0480147 57.982986, 8.598667 57.112833)';

select 
    location.STUnion(@g1) 
from 
    mp_ices_areas 
where 
    ICES_AREA in ('IIIa', 'IVa', 'IVb')
```

[Original map with new border line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnxKW.png)

The result should be like this:

[Corrected map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRgql.jpg)

**What needs to be done:**
If you look at the first picture then the border beween the three areas (blue, purple and orange) looks like a staircase.

The areas needs to be changed so that this border between these three areas follows the thin red line instead (I tried to visualize the wanted result in the last picture).

I have coordinates of the red line (start and end point), so it must be possible somehow to make some SQL that could either update the geography object or help me manually create a new WKT string.

Comment: Just `update` with the value `location.STUnion(@g1)`? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Please state your problem clearly.

Comment: Any suggestions, or is my problem still unclear? I see two solutions 1: Make some query that somehows gives me the ppoints that are on the "wrong" side of the intersection between one of the areas and the red line and then manully manipulate the WKT behind each geography object or 2: make a query that updates the geography object. But how to do that?